# excel 2010 vba. sql query over columns 'like' vlookup

Tags: sql, ms-access, excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a "Filename.accdb" (2010) file to which I established a connection with Excel's VBA.

Let's say that within the file I have a TableA:

```
Column1 Column2 Worker
------- ------- -------
Text1   Text2   15
Text3   Text4   4
...
Text5   Text6   20
```

And a TableB:

```
ID      Name
------- -------
1       Name1
4       Name4
15      Name15
...
20      Name20
```

I am able to import those tables into a worksheet, but what I'd like to achieve is this:

Desired query result (I don't want the whole TableA):

```
Column1 Worker
------- -------
Text1   Name15
Text3   Name4
...
Text5   Name20
```

At the moment, I am importing both tables separately and then writing the values of the "Name" column into the "Worker" column. I achieve this with a for loop and the function Vlookup(...).
It's fast and works fine, so what is my problem?

Well, it generates plenty of code and I am sure that it must be possible by a sql query.
Also, I think I would learn a lot from this as I am quite new to sql.

This is my string so far ...

```
sql = "SELECT TableA.Column1, TableA.Worker, TableB.Name " & _
      "FROM TableA " & _
      "LEFT JOIN TableB " & _
      "ON TableB.ID = TableA.Worker"
```

It doesn't work and throws the "... cannot perform join on multiple fields error ..."
I couldn't find a solution for me in the internet.

Does anyone see the problem?
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

TableB.ID is a numeric column, the column you want from your description, is Name:

```
sql = "SELECT TableA.Column1, TableA.Worker, TableB.Name " & _
      "FROM TableA " & _
      "LEFT JOIN TableB " & _
      "ON TableB.Name = TableA.Worker"
```

Note that Name is not a good choice for a column name. It is always wise to test your queries in MS Access, the query design window is a great place to start.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try it but our network is down at the moment.

Comment: Does not work and I gave it up after some while. It might even be that Access cannot handle such queries and I am too unexperienced to know.